# SSIS - merging non linked parts of xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

i have xml that has complex structure and while i was able to pull set of data i need from this sensor like measurements "from" and "to" and "count", I also have to pull data about sensor like IP address and Serial number that lives in different tag which doesn't have same id as the data tags. Here is the XML:

```
<response xmlns="http://www.test.com/sensor-api/v2">
<sensor-time timezone="America/New_York">2017-07-18T15:45:03-04:00</sensor-time>
  <status>
    <code>OK</code>
  </status>
<sensor-info>
  <serial-number>Q3:80:39:40:9Z:N2</serial-number>
  <ip-address>192.163.135.10</ip-address>
  <name>Test</name>
  <group />
  <device-type>PC2 - UL</device-type>
</sensor-info>
<content>
  <elements>
    <element>
      <element-id>2</element-id>
      <element-name>Conf_Lower_Zone</element-name>
      <sensor-type>SINGLE_SENSOR</sensor-type>
      <data-type>ZONE</data-type>
      <from>2017-07-18T15:40:00-04:00</from>
      <to>2017-07-18T15:45:00-04:00</to>
      <resolution>ONE_MINUTE</resolution>
        <measurements>
          <measurement>
            <from>2017-07-18T15:40:00-04:00</from>
            <to>2017-07-18T15:41:00-04:00</to>
             <values>
               <value label="count">0</value>
             </values>
          </measurement>
          <measurement>
            <from>2017-07-18T15:41:00-04:00</from>
            <to>2017-07-18T15:42:00-04:00</to>
               <values>
                 <value label="count">0</value>
               </values>
          </measurement>
```

I used SSIS package with merge join process and i was able to push data in to SQL table now i have to add the sensor info ( IP, Serial) to the same table. So Serial and IP would repeat for every row of data of course. 
How do i do this in SSIS package? What process to use to add two additional columns to repeat data all the way down for every line.
Here is the SSIS package so far:
[image]

Ok so I edited the SSIS package deriving two differing output from XML Source, one with Sensor-Info that feeds that Sensor_Info Table in SQL Server, and another output from XML Source that feeds Count_Data Table in SQL Server. 
Than I added the Execute SQL Task within foreach Look Container as on image bellow, and i added this Query

```
    USE SANDBOX
    GO
    INSERT INTO ALL_DATA
    SELECT *
    FROM [SANDBOX].[dbo].[Sensor_Info],[dbo].[Count_Data]
```

This is in attempt to Combine these two tables after each XML Load. However i am getting trash data which does combine the tables but with no sense.
What am I doing wrong now?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I find it so much easier to deserialize XML in C# into classes and work with it with loops.

Answer (score 0):

One of your XML outputs should be sensor-info.

You should run that through a script component transformation:

Set up some variables for @IP and @SerNum and include in variables.
Check both IP and SerialNumber columns as input columns.

Enter the script and it is simply this.

```
Variables.IP = Row.IP.ToString();
Variables.SerNum = Row.SerialNumber.TOString();
```

Now add a derived column in the flow that you want to add these values and set them to the variables you just defined.

Comment: You may want to make this a separate data flow to not get ahead of yourself since you are processing these outputs simultaneously.

Comment: You actually have to make this a separate data flow or the variables will not be updated.